# How to sort List for a specific date and time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a list which I want to sort and show the entries for a specific date and time.

```
public class Foodlist
{
    public int C_ID { get; set; }
    public string DateofFood{ get; set;}
    public string FoodTime{ get; set;}
    public string FoodDetail{ get; set;}
}
```

currently I am using the following code to show the list in descending order by date. The date format is same as that of the date picker.

```
var datetime = foodItems.OrderBy(x => x.DateofFood).ToList();    
listBox1.ItemsSource = datetime;
```

I want to show only the entries for a specific date, say Today. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.Where` to filter the data:

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = orderedList; 
var datetime = 
    foodItems
    .Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.DateofFood).Date == datePickerValue.Date) //Or whatever the date time is you're after.
    .OrderBy(x => x.DateofFood)
    .ToList();
```

It might be better to make the `DateofFood` a `DateTime` in your class though to avoid using `DateTime.Parse()` (or `ParseExcact()` if needed).

```
.Where(x => x.DateofFood.Date == datePickerValue.Date) //Or whatever the date time is you're after.
```

Notice the use of `.Date` to remove the Time component of the `DateTime` so you can find entries on a given date.

Comment: Works Perfectly :) Thanks a lot. Very well explained :)

Comment: do you have any ideas how to compare date as well as time? Here DateofFood Represents date value and FoodTime as the time of food.

Comment: @ShubhamM  `.Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.DateofFood).Date == datePickerValue.Date && DateTime.Parse(x.FoodTime).Time == datePickerValue.Time)` ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of DateTime structure:

```
var result = foodItems.OrderBy(x => x.DateofFood)
                      .Where(x=>x.DateofFood.Date == givenDate.Date).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to apply predicate in where like

```
var datetime = foodItems.Where(x=>x.DateofFood==DateTime.Today).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var datetime = foodItems.Where(x => x.DateofFood == DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing it as string, then it might be a better option to store it as yyyyMMdd. As this will provide you simple sorting.

While you can always do `System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMmMdd")`for comparison with above list.